# Heap allocation of abstract class

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am wondering why I cannot initialize an array of abstract objects to the stack but not the heap.

Here is some C++ code similar to mine that fails on the last line. I'm mainly just curious with the reasons behind this problem dealing with the heap vs. the stack. Thanks in advance!

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

class Obj {
public:
    virtual void fn() =0;
};

class Sub : public Obj {
public:
    void fn() {
        // ...
    }
};

Obj * o1_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
Obj * o2_array = new Obj[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Compiler Error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing two very different things. In the "stack" case,

```
Obj * o1_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

you are initializing an array of *pointers*. You don't need a complete or non-abstract type for this. In the "heap" case,

```
Obj * o2_array = new Obj[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

you are initializing an array of *objects* on the RHS and assigning the address of the first element to a pointer in the LHS. You need a complete, non-abstract type to build the array. If you want a dynamically-sized collection of pointers, a good bet is to use a container of pointers (assuming something else takes care of the management of the pointees' lifetime) or a container of smart pointers (where the smartness of the pointer decides who manages the pointee).

Non-managing:

```
std::vector<Obj*> o1_array(ARRAY_SIZE);
```

Managing (unique ownership):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj>> o1_array(ARRAY_SIZE);
```

For more options on containers managing "pointers", see the [**boost pointer container library**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: So is there any way to define the array dynamically and still be able to use an abstract class, so that I can polymorphically loop through the array and still be able to change its size?

Comment: @Cameron Sure, you could instantiate an array (or container) of pointers. I'll add an example.